# Hiding Woocommerce Sidebar on Single Product Pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new here.

I have installed a sidebar on my Woocommerce shop page like so (in a woocommerce.php file):

```
<main role="main" class="container row">
    <div class="col-md-2 filtersmargin">
        <?php
        if (is_active_sidebar('sidebar')) {
            dynamic_sidebar('sidebar');
        }
        ?> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="woocommerce">
            <?php woocommerce_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </main><!-- /.container -->
```

However, this sidebar is of course also displaying on single product pages. The problem is just that the filters in my sidebar are irrelevant when viewing a single product (size, color, etc.) and therefore I would like to remove it from there. I have done so succesfully in the past with snippets from Google (when I did not create my own custom theme but used Astra), but now I cannot make it work anymore. I suspect it is due to the way that I am integrating the sidebar in the first place, but I am not sure.

If anyone have any ideas as to how I can remove it only on the single product pages, that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Try to use css like : `.filtersmargin{display:none!important;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use a conditional statement checking what kind of page you are in.

[You can find more functions and details here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/)

The code might look something like

```
<main role="main" class="container row">
<?php if (! is_product() ){  //if not single product page ?>
<div class="col-md-2 filtersmargin">
    <?php
    if (is_active_sidebar('sidebar')) {
        dynamic_sidebar('sidebar');
    }
    ?> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
<?php }else{ // this depends on how you want your template to look ?>
  <div class="col-md-12">
<?php } ?>
    <div class="woocommerce">
        <?php woocommerce_content(); ?>
    </div>

</main><!-- /.container -->
```

If you want that column to just be empty on single product page you can just change the one line:

```
if ( is_active_sidebar('sidebar') && ! is_product() ) {
```

I'm not sure which template file you are editing so it might be worth while looking into that.

Side note:If you are editing the files inside the WooCommerce plugin, remember it's better to copy template files into your theme/child-theme and override them that way so you can update your plugin without loosing changes to the templates.

Comment: This is brilliant. Your first suggestion is exactly what I needed. I had tried some if-else statements myself, but they were placed in the functions.php file. 

I was worried that I would end up with empty space because of the bootstrap columns, but your solution took that into account! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

a way is to check if it is single product by `is_product()` or `is_singular('product')` functions and if it is not show sidebar.

an other way is to completely copy `template` folder from **woocommerce** plugins root, and paste it into **themes/current-theme/woocommerce** and then customize `single-product.php` file.

*note:* you don't need to copy all files. you can only copy files that you need to customize (here is `single-product.php`).